# Closest pair of points a different approach

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I was trying to solve this problem and I came up with a solution as below, which is quite different than the "Wikipedia" algorithm. I am failing to understand what is wrong with my solution, which is also O(nlogn).

**Input**: Set of co-ordinates along x-y axis. {(2,4),(5,3),(3,7),(4,2),(6,3)}

**My Solution:**

1. Sort given set wrt x-coordinates. {(2,4),(3,7),(4,2),(5,3),(6,3)} .
   Complexity O(nlog)
2. Find the min{distance between consecutive pair}, lets call it min_x. 
   Complexity O(n)
3. Sort given set wrt y-coordinates. {(4,2),(5,3),(6,3),(2,4),(3,7)} . Complexity O(nlog)
4. Find the min{distance between consecutive pair}, lets call it min_y. Complexity O(n)
5. min_d = min(min_x, min_y) the pair which resulted in min_d is the pair with shortest distance.

Is this wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: "Is this wrong?" <- So your tests pass?

Comment: I mean, I am not able to find counter example to prove this as wrong. Thats whats creating the confusion.

Comment: in the example you're giving, the data sets don't seem to match.

Comment: This is a problem right ? I need to understand why my solution is wrong. If you still think otherwise, I will delete this question. Thanks !

Comment: @Timothy Groote : Sorry, corrected now.

Comment: The algorithm is sort given set with x-coordinate for each consecutive pair find minimum distance. Sort with y-coordinates and do the same. Which ever pair gives min distance is shortest pair.

Comment: What does your algorithm calculate for this set of points: {(2,2), (4,4), (3,10), (10,3)}?

Comment: Thanks  Pieter Geerkens@, I got my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is wrong.  Consider the set { (0, 0), (0, 10), (10, 0), (0.2, 0.2) } as a counter example.  Your approach will never have (0,0) and (0.2, 0.2) as consecutive elements in either ordering and therefore will never be found as the two points closest to each other.

Answer (score 3):

You algorithm will yield a faulty optimal pair for e.g. the following example:

```
var points : [(Int,Int)] = [(0,0),(1,10),(10,1),(3,3)]

/* xmin solution: (1,10), (3,3) (dist = sqrt(4+49) = sqrt(53))
   from sorted list: (0,0),(1,10),(3,3),(10,1)                 */

/* ymin solution: (10,1), (3,3) (dist = sqrt(53))
   from sorted list: (0,0),(10,1),(3,3),(1,10)                 */

/* real solution: (0,0), (3,3) (dist = sqrt(18) < sqrt(53))    */
```

Comment: @RajvidyaChandele Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is wrong. It's not at necessary that for  sqrt(`x^2 + y^2`)  is minimum when either of x^2 or y^2 is minimum.

The best known solution has Time complexity of O(nlogn).
A solution may be found in the text [Here](https://mcdtu.files.wordpress.com/2017/03/introduction-to-algorithms-3rd-edition-sep-2010.pdf) Section 33.4 page 1039.

No need of reading the whole chapter just section 33.4 would suffice.